# unable to increase my ajax calender extender width in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i want to increase width of asp.net ajax calender control . but im not getting property to set width

```
        <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Follow Up Date" CssClass="col-lg-3 control-label"></asp:Label>
                        <div class="col-lg-7">


                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFollowupDate" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Follow Up Date" CssClass="form-control"
                                TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>

                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFollowupDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: For that you need to make changes via CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .test .ajax__calendar_body 
    {
      width:200px;
      background:white;
      border:1px black;
    }
</style>

<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtdatepickerFrom" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" CssClass="test">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Just call css class in asp:CalendarExtender